# How to disable CDPurgeableResultCache logs?

Tags: swift, xcode

Currently whenever I run my mac application my debug output gets filled with the same thing over and over again:

```
2023-03-08 23:06:15.692878+0100 UtilityTools[43807:2280795] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /System/Volumes/VM, setting to zero
2023-03-08 23:06:15.693537+0100 UtilityTools[43807:2280795] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /System/Volumes/Update, setting to zero
2023-03-08 23:06:15.694138+0100 UtilityTools[43807:2280795] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /System/Volumes/Preboot, setting to zero
2023-03-08 23:06:15.694736+0100 UtilityTools[43807:2280795] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /System/Volumes/iSCPreboot, setting to zero
2023-03-08 23:06:15.695335+0100 UtilityTools[43807:2280795] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /System/Volumes/Hardware, setting to zero
2023-03-08 23:06:15.709811+0100 UtilityTools[43807:2280795] [client] 114 CDPurgeableResultCache _recentPurgeableTotals no result for /System/Volumes/xarts, setting to zero
```

This makes debugging very hard and annoying, so I would like to disable it somehow.

Here is the code causing it:

```
func getFreeSpace() -> Double {
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory())
    do {
        let values = try fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey]) // THIS LINE
        if let capacity: Int64 = values.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage {
            return Double(capacity)
        }
    } catch {

    }
    return 1
}
```

Thanks in advance.